# What goes into the () of a catch?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I am using the following code:

```
catch (Exception ex) { 
    processException(ex); 
    return View("CreateEdit", vm); 
}
```

Is it necessary to declare the exception "Exception ex".  I am wondering does a catch block 
ever have anything in the parenthesis that follows that is not related to the something 
derived from Exception?

Comment: As the answers below indicate, stating the type (class) of exception that you wish to catch is mandatory. However, declaring a *variable* of that type is optional. You only need to do so if you want to use the exception object inside of the `catch` block. Otherwise, you can simply write `catch (Exception)` or even better, handle a specific more derived exception, `catch (FileNotFoundException)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the catch block you will have to give the type of exception you want to catch. All those types have to be derived from the class `System.Exception`

It is best not to catch exceptions of type `Exception` directly and rather catch specific exceptions. A catch block that handles System.Exception(if present) is best specified last.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No; it must always be an argument of type `Exception` or something derived from it.

That part specifies what type of exception - and its derived classes - is being caught within that `catch` block. For instance, consider:

```
try
{
    //stuff...
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
   //do stuff with divide by zero...
}
catch (MyCustomException ex)
{
   //do stuff with my custom exception...
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   //do stuff with IO Exception...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //handle all other exceptions
}
```

The order of the `catch` clauses is vital, if there are multiple. They must always go from most derived to least; If I put the last block `Exception` at the top, it would catch all exceptions, and the other, more derived blocks would catch nothing.

It's also possible to leave off the most generic `Exception` in order to let other types of exceptions bubble up the stack to the next level.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, when you catch something of a specific type, it must be `Exception` or a type derived from `Exception`.  Other .NET languages (e.g. C++/CLI) support throwing non-`Exception` types, and the only way to catch those is to use an "empty catch", i.e. `catch { ... }` -- but this is only useful in very rare cases (mostly when doing interop with other libraries).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not mandatory. In the catch block you are declaring an object of System.Exception class, which holds the details of the raised exception.

You can declare how you want, as it's just convention using `Exception Ex`. The class in parentheses is the type of exception caught. If you do not use parentheses, then you have throw your exception using a `throw` statement.

For example these are all valid:

```
catch (Exception ex) { }
catch (Exception e ) { }
catch (Exception objEx) { }
```